# Write to File's Last 32 Characters

Tags: c++, file, ofstream, file-processing

I want to write an info to binary file's last 32 characters. But when i call my writeInfo function, it deletes the whole content. I can read the data before i write, but after i write with this function, it deletes the whole content, instead of writing.

```
void Info::writeInfo(char *filedestination)
{
ofstream test;
test.open(filedestination, ios::binary); 
test.seekp(-32, ios::end); // not sure about seekp
test.write(info, 31);
test.close();
}
```

Hope you can help, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open the file in read-write mode to prevent the call to `open` from truncating it:

```
test.open(filedestination, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

try using fseek(). link above is documentation

Comment: That is the C equivalent of `seekp`, which he is already using. Also mixing C and C++ is a bad idea.